# unintended lines in the viewport

Tags: edit-mode

I'm getting very frustrated here! I'm creating very simple shapes in blender, but for some reason I keep creating multiple vertices that overlap eachother. When I move my object forward, these hidden vertices reveal themselves to angry me with their presence. The image below is just one example. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Some help would be much appreciated.

I basically just start with a plane and mirror it. I then extrude the edges and move them towards the centre to create the neckline for my character's clothing. I keep getting these unintended vertices. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? [image]